# How to check that all tasks have been properly completed?

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0, task, task-parallel-library

I have the following lines in my code:

```
    var taskA = Task.Factory.StartNew(WorkA);
    var taskB = Task.Factory.StartNew(WorkB);
    var allTasks = new[] { taskA, taskB };

    Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(allTasks, tasks => FinalWork(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
```

But when I run this, I get the following error:

> It is invalid to exclude specific continuation kinds for continuations off of multiple tasks.

Which is caused by the option **TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion**.

My question is how to check that all tasks have done their work properly (all tasks statuses are **RanToCompletion**) and then do **FinalWork()**?
In the meantime, the application performs other tasks.

Comment: What do you want to do if some of the `Task`s fail?

Comment: If some of the `Task`s fail nothing should be done.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Based on @Peter Ritchie and @Ben McDougall answers I found a solution. I modified my code by removing redundant variable `tasks` and `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion`

```
var taskA = Task.Factory.StartNew(WorkA);
var taskB = Task.Factory.StartNew(WorkB);
var allTasks = new[] { taskA, taskB };
Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(allTasks, FinalWork);
```

Where `FinalWork` is:

```
private static void FinalWork(Task[] tasks)
{
   if (tasks.All(t => t.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion))
   {
        // do "some work"
   }
}
```

If all `tasks` have status `RanToCompletion`, **"some work"** will be done. It  will be performed immediately after all tasks have completed and will not block the main task.
If I cancel at least one of the tasks, nothing will be done.

Alternatively you can do this,

```
var taskA = Task.Factory.StartNew(WorkA);
var taskB = Task.Factory.StartNew(WorkB);
var allTasks = new[] { taskA, taskB };
var continuedTask = Task.WhenAll(allTasks).ContinueWith((antecedent) => { /*Do Work*/ }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion));
```

Comment: The alternative seems the way to go - even [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netframework-4.8) suggest it.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't provided any code that does anything with any of the tasks that ran to completion (your `tasks` variable is ignored).  You'd get the same result if you simply removed `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion`.  i.e. If you *could* use `ContinueWhenAll` with `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion` your continuation isn't going to be called until all tasks have either completed or failed.  If you don't do anything with just the completed tasks, that's the same as `Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(allTasks, tasks => FinalWork());`

If there's something more specific that you want to do, please provide the details so that someone might be able to help you.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Now I see that variable `tasks` is redundant. All informations about tasks statuses may be passed to function through variable `allTasks`.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the actual question you posed:

> My question is how to check that all tasks have done their work properly (all tasks statuses are RanToCompletion) and then do FinalWork()? In the meantime, the application performs other tasks.

at least that is what I read as the question check the following code:

```
    var taskA = Task.Factory.StartNew(WorkA);
    var taskB = Task.Factory.StartNew(WorkB);
    var allTasks = new[] { taskA, taskB };

    taskA.Wait();
    taskB.Wait();

    if (taskA.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion && taskB.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
        Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(allTasks, tasks => FinalWork());
    else
        //do something
```

You actually answered the question yourself with your question if you did mean that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Unfortunately, this solution is blocking the main task by using the method `Task.Wait`

Comment: @Zen I added some Tasks in between the declaration of the tasks and the Wait and they execute nicely withour locking will look into your problem again later.

Comment: @Zen: I added a new class and containing a Thread and it all works nicely. Nothing is locking, everything is running smoothly. I will need some more information on your problem as I do not have any difficulty so far. Basically added a Class which starts a thread in the constructor and added it before the tasks:
`code`
    var taskC = Task.Factory.StartNew(WorkC);
    JustAnotherThread jt = new JustAnotherThread(); 

    var taskA = Task.Factory.StartNew(WorkA);`code`