# How do I invoke method after a task is completed?

Tags: c#, task

Hello I'm trying to alert the user when all images have been properly deep zoomed and zipped. Each image is asynchronously deep zoomed and zipped and after all images have been successfully deep zoomed and zipped I wish to alert the user with a pop up.

```
var z = Task.Factory.StartNew(
() =>
{
    cr.Create(current_file_name, output);
    File.Copy(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\HTMLViewer.html", outputPath + "\\HTMLViewer.html", true);

    ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(outputPath, Directory.GetParent(outputPath) + "\\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(current_file_name) + ".zip");
});

var tasks = new[] { z };
var continued = Task.WhenAll(tasks).ContinueWith((antecedent) =>
{
    _window.MainDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(
    () =>
    {
        _popUp.PopUpText = "DeepZoom completed";
        _popUp.BeginPopUpTimer();
    }));
}, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
```

I used the followed solution as an example : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12248832/how-to-check-that-all-tasks-have-been-properly-completed#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12248832/how-to-check-that-all-tasks-have-been-properly-completed#_=_) but I can't seem to get it working. So just to clarify; this code is within a foreach that iterates through a set of images. When all images have been successfully zipped, I want the `_popUp.BeginPopUpTimer` method to be invoked.

Comment: have you tried to await the resulting task? `await continue`

Comment: @Gusman if you're refering to the continued variable, it's as if the Task.WhenAll(tasks) ... is never met, as if the task z is never completed.

Comment: If this code is within a foreach, shouldn't you be building an array of all the tasks in the loop ,then call task.Whenall on all the tasks in one go, instead of having N calls to Task.Whenall each with a singleton array?

Comment: @JonasH Yes that's a good point too, thanks buddy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use async await

```
private async Task DoMyWork()
{
    var z = Task.Factory.StartNew(
    () =>
    {
        cr.Create(current_file_name, output);
        File.Copy(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\HTMLViewer.html", outputPath + "\\HTMLViewer.html", true);

        ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(outputPath, Directory.GetParent(outputPath) + "\\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(current_file_name) + ".zip");
    });

    var tasks = new[] { z };
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    _window.MainDispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        _popUp.PopUpText = "DeepZoom completed";
        _popUp.BeginPopUpTimer();
    });
}
```

When you have only one task you do not have to use `Task.WhenAll`. You can use use:

```
await Task.Factory.StartNew(
() =>
{
    cr.Create(current_file_name, output);
    File.Copy(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\HTMLViewer.html", outputPath + "\\HTMLViewer.html", true);

    ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(outputPath, Directory.GetParent(outputPath) + "\\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(current_file_name) + ".zip");
});

_window.MainDispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    _popUp.PopUpText = "DeepZoom completed";
    _popUp.BeginPopUpTimer();
});
```

Comment: I added await both at Task.Factory.StartNew and at the dispatcher. I believe it did the trick, though there's another complication that occurred, but it has nothing to do with this. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: by the way @Kedrzu while I have you here. I seem to have my posts downvoted whenever I post here (or well once in a while). I've read the rules and I'm pretty sure I've followed the desired posting rules, what did I do wrong here :)?

Comment: I'm not sure why you were downvoted. I'm beginner in helping here :-) Maybe your last sentences were a litle bit unclear.

Comment: Could be, I thought I was clarifying ^^ Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I invoke method after a task is completed?

Use `await`.

Also:

- [Don't use `StartNew`; it's dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html). Use `Task.Run` instead.
- [Don't use `ContinueWith`; it is also dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html). Use `await` instead.
- Don't use `BeginInvoke`. Use `await` or `IProgress<T>` instead.

Applying these best practices, the code is considerably simplified:

```
await Task.Run(() =>
{
  cr.Create(current_file_name, output);
  File.Copy(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\HTMLViewer.html", outputPath + "\\HTMLViewer.html", true);

  ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(outputPath, Directory.GetParent(outputPath) + "\\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(current_file_name) + ".zip");
});

_popUp.PopUpText = "DeepZoom completed";
_popUp.BeginPopUpTimer();
```